# How to configure OSB to consume messages from Amazon SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, osb

I'm newbie to AWS and trying to work on the SQS for the first time. I've an Oracle Service Bus (OSB) in non-cloud environment and would like to configure OSB to consume messages from Amazon SQS. The documentation mentions to use REST API and poll repeatedly for messages. I also read about the 'client library for JMS' so that the OSB could treat SQS as JMS provider. What is the best approach to achieve this? Appreciate your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

The *easiest* (not necessarily the purest way) would be to create a Java EE app that imports the SQS libraries and pulls messages from AWS and puts them on a local queue for OSB to process. The [example code snippets](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/jmsclient.html) are in Java, so it should be relatively straight forward.

The purest way would be to set it up as a [remote JMS provider](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/jms/interop.html). However, how to set that up is not so clear - you may end up writing most of the code that went into option #1 above, but making a JMS client library instead of a MDB.